# Wordpress Returning function within Shortcode displaying top of the page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode, ultimate-member

I am trying to use a shortcode to display Ultimate Member form, the issue I have is the output of the shortcode always displays at the top of the page and not where I placed the shortcode.

I think its outputting acf_form(settings) as soon as the shortcode is called and not returning it.

```
function op_profile_skills_func (){
    $form = acf_form($settings);
    return $form; 
}
add_shortcode('op_profile_skills', 'op_profile_skills_func');
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong, any thoughts?  I have tried echo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you supposed, the function is printing the form rather than returning it.

What you can do is to capture the output using an output buffer:

```
function op_profile_skills_func (){
    ob_start();
    acf_form($settings);
    $form = ob_get_clean();
    return $form; 
}
```

Everything echoed or printed between *start* and *clean* will be collected and passed to `$form`.